# Add text to hamburger icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I add text to bootstrap hamburger item? Normally it shows as three horizontal lines. I would like to put text to the right or left.

Imagine this is hamburger icon: `[=]`

Here is how I want it to look like: `Expand menu [=]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are describing as a "hamburger icon" is simply a `button` with 3 `span`, each one with the class `icon-bar`.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
                                            data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

You should be able to wrap this button inside a `<div>` element and style it however you like.